# Screenshot on ubuntu on a chromebook

Tags: 16.04, chromebook, screenshot

I am running ubuntu 16.04 on an acer chromebook and I was wondering if there is anyway to do a screenshot?

Comment: Have you tried downloading shutter from the Ubuntu Software Centre?

Comment: @Graham I don't think you can get it for ubuntu version 16.04

Comment: @ T. Green I use it regularly and I'm in 16.04 LTS

Comment: I can't download anything from the Ubuntu Software Centre

Comment: Don't you have the application named `screenshot`? (GNOME screenshot)

Comment: @muclux not that I can find

Comment: The package `shutter` is definitively available for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @Videonauth where can I get it from?

Comment: make sure you have activated the universe repository and then simply type in terminal `sudo apt install shutter`